Set custom color on a Datepicker Dialog in Kotlin
So, total begginner here and im trying to do a datepicker dialog in android studio. Everything works fine but i have no idea how to change the color of the dialog.
My code looks like this
 val datePicker = DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { view, years, month, dayOfMonth ->

            myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, years)
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month)
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth)

            updateLable(myCalendar)
        }

        btnDatePicker.setOnClickListener{
            DatePickerDialog(this, datePicker, myCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show()
        }

can someone help me with this ?
I tried looking for a solution online but it's always in older version of android or the code straight up doesn't work :/

your .xml file
<style name="CustomDatePickerDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <!-- Customize these colors according to your needs -->
    <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#BDBDBD</item>
    <item name="android:background">#3F51B5</item>
</style>

update the code your provided
val datePicker = DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { view, years, month, dayOfMonth ->
    myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, years)
    myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month)
    myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth)
    updateLabel(myCalendar)
}

btnDatePicker.setOnClickListener {
    DatePickerDialog(
        this, 
        R.style.CustomDatePickerDialog, // Apply the custom style here
        datePicker, 
        myCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), 
        myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), 
        myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
    ).show()
}

DatePickerDialog should reflect the custom colors you defined in the CustomDatePickerDialog style
If needed update your AndroidManifest.xml ading AppCompat theme.
<application
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
</application>


Almost works but now "Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog" shows an error "cannot resolve symbol"

@Azyoko could you please open build.gradle and check if there is androidx.appcompat:appcompat:x.x.x

there's androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner but no androidx.appcompat

@Azyoko then add it and click sync now : androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1

where ? do i replace androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner ?

@Azyoko just add an other line

Awesome it works, thanks a lot ! but do you have an idea how to change the "cancel" and "ok" button ?

@Azyoko, to customize the Cancel and OK buttons in a DatePickerDialog, you'll need to create a custom dialog layout. I recommend accepting the above answer and attempting to implement the custom dialog layout as described. If you face any issues, feel free to open a new topic where you can explain where you're stuck and provide details on what you've tried so far. This approach will help others assist you more effectively.
